# What is wrong with this line in my program?

Tags: java, arrays

```
System.out.println(numArray[i] "which is" (100*numArray[i]/theSum) " % of the sum.");
```

Everything in my program seems to be fine except this last line. I tried everything I could think of and it still displays an error.

```
- The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved 
     to int
    - Syntax error on token ""which is"", [ expected
    - Syntax error on token "" % of the sum."", ] expected
    - Syntax error on token "" % of the sum"", ] expected
    - Syntax error on token "", which is"", [ expected
```

That is what it displays. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're missing `+` operators that allow you to concatenate your String. i.e., `numArray[i] + "which is" + (100*numArray[i]/theSum) + " % of the sum."`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
System.out.println(numArray[i] "which is" (100*numArray[i]/theSum) " % of the sum.");
```

to

```
System.out.println(numArray[i] + "which is" + (100*numArray[i]/theSum) + " % of the sum.");
```

`+` -> used to concatenate strings.